# Работоспособность шелла у пользователя Debian 8

Tags: linux, bash, debian, shell, sh

При вводе от root, команды:

**root@s3:~# sudo -H -u testuser ./start.sh 

sudo: ./start.sh: command not found**

Также не работает команда **cd**

Так я создаю пользователя:
**useradd -m -g testgroup testuser &&
  chown testuser -Rf /home/testuser &&
  chmod 755 /home/testuser**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

./start.sh находится в папке /root/ куда нет доступа тестузеру. Поместите скрипты в /opt/ или в домашнюю папку пользователя

Comment: start.sh и так находится по пути /home/testuser/start.sh

Ведь у меня также нету доступа к команде cd, её вовсе не существует

Comment: Текст вопроса говорит об обратном

Comment: Я разобрался. Спасибо огромное, ваш ответ мне очень сильно помог!